# Why does my partitions not mount while windows has been shut down?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, ntfs, partitioning

Error mounting `/dev/sda2` at `/media/lubia/Media`: Command-line

```
mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/lubia/Media"'
exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
```

Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.

```
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Searching for your error message immediately shows several results including the duplicate above. You should consider searching before asking a new question. If, instead, your question is substantially different from the aforementioned one, please clarify what is different in your case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn off **fast boot** and **hibernation** in Windows. Next, once you're in Windows, run this in an administrative console window:

```
chkdsk /f C:
```

(assuming `sda2` is `C:`)

It'll tell you that you can't do that on a running Windows OS (if this is the `C:` drive) and ask if you wish to run it at boot time. Say yes. Once the `sda2` partition has a clean file system, you'll be able to mount it in Ubuntu.

Of course, another question might be... do you *need* to mount this partition in Ubuntu?